# QT5 register NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification and NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification

Tags: qt

How can I get notified when `NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification` and `NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification` get triggered on OS X?

I want to reset a `QTcpSocket` when the computer comes back from sleep. For some reason `connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));` does not always get triggered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089096/knowing-when-the-system-has-gone-to-sleep-in-a-menu-extra

Comment: But how to make that work in QT?

Comment: Qt won't help you. You'll have to mix Qt with Cocoa. It is possible, but you'll have to try not to get in Qt's way (it is using Cocoa, too).

Comment: Qt provides a run loop in each thread that has a Qt event loop running, so the integration is trivial. Just add a .mm file with relevant Cocoa code to your project and you're all set. Nothing Qt-specific at all is needed. You can send a Qt signal from an objective-C/C++ method.